# I need help on how to save dictionary elements into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I intend to save a contact list with name and phone number in a .csv file from user input through a dictionary.

The problem is that only the name is saved on the .csv file and the number is omitted.

```
contacts={}
def phone_book():
   running=True
   while running:
    command=input('A(dd D)elete L)ook up Q)uit: ')
    if command=='A' or command=='a':
        name=input('Enter new name: ')
        print('Enter new number for', name, end=':' )
        number=input()
        contacts[name]=number
    elif command=='D' or command=='d':
        name= input('Enter the name to delete: ')
        del contacts[name]
    elif command=='L' or command=='l':
        name= input('Enter name to search: ')
        if name in contacts:
             print(name, contacts[name])
        else:
            print("The name is not in the phone book, use A or a to save")
    elif command=='Q' or command=='q':
        running= False
    elif command =='list':
        for k,v in contacts.items():
            print(k,v)
    else:
        print(command, 'is not a valid command')
def contact_saver():
  import csv
  global name
  csv_columns=['Name', 'Phone number']
  r=[contacts]
  with open(r'C:\Users\Rigelsolutions\Documents\numbersaver.csv', 'w') as f:
        dict_writer=csv.writer(f)
        dict_writer.writerow(csv_columns)
        for data in r:
            dict_writer.writerow(data)
phone_book()
contact_saver()
```

Comment: Hello, could you specify your question : what is the problem with your code, and what are you looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

as I am reading your code `contacts` will look like

```
{
    'name1': '1',
    'name2': '2'
}
```

keys are the names and the value is the number.

but when you did `r = [contacts]` and iterating over r `for data in r` that will mess up I guess your code since you are passing dictionary value to `writerow` instead of a list [name, number]

You can do two things here. parse properly the contacts by:

```
for k, v in contacts.items():
    dict_writer.writerow([k, v])
```

Or properly construct the contacts into a list with dictionaries inside

```
[{
    'name': 'name1',
    'number': 1
}]
```

so you can create DictWriter

```
fieldnames = ['name', 'number']
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

...
# then you can insert by
for contact in contacts:
    writer.writerow(contact)  # which should look like writer.writerow({'name': 'name1', 'number': 1})
```

Comment: thanks a lot this worked perfectly
    for k,v in contacts.items():
                dict_writer.writerow([k,v])